# Get all files names in current directory

Tags: c, file

I try to get all files name sin current directory of my C program. I have next code:

```
#include <glob.h>
glob_t getFiles()
{
    glob_t data;

    switch(glob("*.*", 0, NULL, &data)) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case GLOB_NOSPACE:
            printf("Out of memory...\n");
            break;
        case GLOB_ABORTED:
            printf("Reading error...\n");
            break;
        case GLOB_NOMATCH:
            printf("No files found...\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return data;
}
```

But my gcc doesn't find glob library. So, how I can get all files name sin current directory? If the code from behind is good, how I can install glob library?

PS I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I am sorry for duplicate. Thanks Jongware for info.

Comment: The *possible* duplicate recommends using the native Windows API. If you want to use POSIX (which may be for more "compatible" code), you could use `dirent`. If you prefer that, mention it in your post and I'll retract the Duplicate vote.